# To store the filenames in an array using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

for m in `ls f-*`
do
$i = 0
echo "$m"
arr[$i] = $m
$i = $i + 1
done
```

I want to store the filenames that starts with f- in an array. The above piece of code is not working.

> EDITED :

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
ls f-* | while read m
do
#echo $m
arr[$i]=$m
i=$((i+1))
done
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[0]=f-1: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[1]=f-10: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[2]=f-15: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[3]=f-2: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[4]=f-20: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[5]=f-3: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[6]=f-4: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[7]=f-5: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[8]=f-6: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[9]=f-7: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[10]=f-8: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[11]=f-9: not found
```

**EDITED1:**

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
for i
do
#echo $m
arr[$i]= f-*i
echo $arr[i]
i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Your `while` loop will be executed in a subshell because of the pipe, so its variable assigments won't be visible when the loop is done.

Comment: Please tell what can be done. I declared the variable m above the i, then also I get the error. How to declare the variable globally so it retains the value

Comment: Use a `for` loop like in my answer.

Comment: Declaring the variable makes no difference. Variable assignments in a child process do not affect the parent process.

Comment: @Barmar : Yeah , Thats correct Barmar . Thanks for making me to understand. The for loop helped me.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a loop.

```
arr=( f-* )
```

Comment: script.sh: 3: script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Are you invoking your script like `sh script.sh`? Make sure you use bash to run bash scripts.

Comment: @glennjackman: you were right, I was using sh and so I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Shell variable assignments can't have any spaces around the `=`, and you don't put `$` before the variable being assigned. You also don't need to use `ls`, just put the wildcard in the `for` statement.

```
i=0     # initialize the variable before the loop
for m in f-*
do
    echo "$m"
    arr[$i]=$m
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[0]=f-1: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[1]=f-10: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[2]=f-15: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[3]=f-2: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[4]=f-20: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[5]=f-3: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[6]=f-4: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[7]=f-5: not found
my_script.sh: 7: my_script.sh: arr[8]=f-6: not found
.. I'm getting an error like this

Comment: Are you missing `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning?

Comment: No .. I have it #!/bin/bash

Comment: It works fine for me. What bash version do you have?

Comment: Please tell How to check the bash version

Comment: @Balmar : Thanks.. Its 4.2.25(1)-release

Comment: That's much newer than my version, I don't see any reason why you should be getting that error.

Comment: @Balmar : I have edited my answer. Please see. I get errors in that. f-* -> is the pattern of the filename that is stored on the disk. So I need to retreive the filenames from the disk.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. `for m in f-*` retrieves the filenames from disk.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working for you. I suggest you use @triplee's answer instead. It's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ls: $(ls)
echo ""

seqmax=0
for file in $(ls ./f-* ); do
    char=$( echo $file | wc -c )
    if [ $char > $seqmax ];then
        seqmax=$char
    fi
done
i=0
for count in $(seq 1 1 $seqmax);do
    for file in $(ls | egrep "^f\-.{$count}$");do
        completearray[$i]=$file
        i=$(expr $i + 1 )
    done
done

echo ${completearray[@]}
```

and this should print out as follows.

```
$ ./script.sh
ls: f-1 f-15 f-16 f-2 f-3 f-one f-two g-1 g-2 g-3 script.sh

f-1 f-2 f-3 f-15 f-16 f-one f-two
```

And if you need it to only get "numbers" not all characters then you can change `for file in $(ls | egrep "^f\-.{$count}$");do` to `for file in $(ls | egrep "^f\-[0-9]{$count}$");do`

Comment: Thanks. But I need to print as f-1,f-2,f-3,f-15,f-16 in this sorted order